# Is there any steps to enable unity (unable to see my icons and terminal windows)

Tags: 14.04, unity

Which steps do we have to perform in Ubuntu 14.04.2 when there's no icons and terminal window...

How to open a terminal window? Because when I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> I still get no response.

Comment: Have you tried switching to one of the consoles? Like with the command "CTRL + ALT + F1".